# Save virtual memory in event of a power outage?

Tags: memory, ups

I believe my understanding of ram is that it holds the state of all programs for fast recall. On a short term basis.

So my question is. Can you have a uninterruptible power supply that would send a signal to a server or desktop, saying there is a power outage, and to store the virtual memory on the hard drive so when it boots the virtual memory could be loaded back into the memory and return to what the computer was doing before the outage.

Now that I am typing I am thinking the OS would have a problem with booting because they are not designed to load ram onto the memory from the hard drive. Unless this was somehow coded in. But I guess i'm asking in theory why don't we have this as a feature?

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for is called "Hybernation" and should be supported on every computer that was build since the last 25 years or so as standard. No joke. This is fundamentally basic and all it does show is that you never ever bothered to read up on the basics of any sort of power management in any decent OS.

https://www.howtogeek.com/102897/whats-the-difference-between-sleep-and-hibernate-in-windows/